# Using My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, settings

In VB.NET, can you store a opacity setting in `My.Settings`? How?

```
Me.Opacity = 1.0R '(1.0R is a Double)
```

What is the `R` / What does it do? And how can I store the `1.0R` or `0.25R` in `My.Settings` ? Or is there a better way to store the user’s setting?

`Me.Opacity = My.Settings.Opacity` 
Go to Settings and set Opacity as a Double that equals 0.5

Then my background image disappears / it is white, semi-transparent and missing labels, yet if I apply the same equals 1.0, it's fine (Go to Settings and set Opacity as a Double that equals 1.0)

Comment: This sounds a lot like you don't actually like an Opacity value of 0.5.  Which would be a common observation, it will turn the *entire window* partially opaque.  Parts of it will be just plain hard to see.

Comment: I do like it when the background image is still an image. When I set it statically, it works fine. But it's like the application can no longer find the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into your project settings and pick the Settings tab; then, create a new User Setting called, for example, `Opacity`, and set its type to `Double`. You can now get and set `My.Settings.Opacity`; by default, user settings will also be saved for you when the application closes.

The `R` [is just a type suffix meaning `Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx) — it’s unnecessary, as `1.0` will be assumed to be a `Double` all the same. Don’t worry, no obscure types here :)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Then I guess my question would be, when I set : 
Me.Opacity = My.Settings.Opacity 
Go to Settings and set Opacity as a Double that equals 0.5 my background image disappears and it is white and missing labels, yet if I apply the same equals 1.0, it's fine.

Comment: @PhilJFry: Does that happen even without `My.Settings` being involved? Say, if you set it to `0.5` directly in `Form_Load`?

Comment: No, I can manually set it (while the form is running(trackbar or radio buttons)) and it is fine, but it doesnt remember the settings when I close the form and re-open it(the form).

Comment: Side note, thank you for the edits in my question. I was having a hard time with the terminology and phrasing of the question. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem! So where are you trying to set it from `My.Settings`? The `Load` event? Try handling a button, see if that works better for some reason.

Comment: I was trying during the `Load` event and also in the formname.designer.vb code. Not sure what that's called. The code behind the formname.vb[design]
I don't have a button on the form I am trying to adjust, or does "handling a button" mean something else?

Comment: @PhilJFry: Sorry, I forgot a word there! Yes, that’s what I meant. Could you maybe try adding a button? Anyways… a) Which operating system are you using? b) Is there any GDI[+] stuff involved here? c) Can you get a screenshot or take a picture of what the form looks like, or reproduce that behaviour in a smaller program?

Comment: Sure. I am about done for the night. I'll put something together tomorrow. 
The website says "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. "
and to move to chat. So maybe we can chat and come back and post the final answer here. Only tested on Windows 8 and that could be an issue. I will also try to duplicate tomorrow on a Windows 7 workstation. Thanks again for all the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

By loading the settings onload

```
Private Sub ... .Load

    Me.Opacity = My.Settings.Opacity

End Sub
```

It is working fine. I have not isolated it down yet, but the main variable between it working and then not working was Windows 8. When I publish the app I will retest on 8 and verify.